# Safari on iOS>=11 block cookies & web storage by default - how to persist (first-party) data?

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, local-storage, ios11

On our app, we show a very simple "onboarding" message for users on their first visit.
We rely on localStorage and when it is not supported fallback on cookies using github.com/Acanguven/StorageService. This data is first party as it's our cookies and they're set for our website. Nothing like adtech or cross-domain cookies/storage: for example just a simple way to not show onboarding modal to users who already visited the website.

The thing is on my iphone it does not work and we get some javascript "Security Error or Access denied" when we try to create those cookies/local storage.

For example one of our data is like this:

```
if ( (window.StorageService.localStorage.getItem('user_already_saw_the_message') !== null) ) {
          showMessage():
        }
        // If user never saw the message, show 1st msg almost immediately
else {
          //do nothing
        }
      }
```

I checked my iphone and indeed it says in Apps>Safari that the line block All cookies is activated/"ON". so it blocks even first party cookies (nothing like cross-domain or some advertising cookies).

So my question has two sub-components:

1. To assess how large/significant the issue is on the userbase: is it just my iphone or do all iphone users who upgraded to iOS11 and soon will upgrade to iOS12 automatically get the default setting of "all cookies blocked = "ON" ?
2. If question 1's answer is "yes all users by default get this all cookies blocked setting", that makes the following question even more crucial as it means, given the market share of iOS, that it affects a tremendous number of users: how do you just persist data like "only show this message once" or "only show this modal once every month" if we can't use cookies nor local/session Storage ?

Comment: If persisting the modal state is that important, you might try persisting this data on the backend. That's a full-proof solution that will always work.

Comment: but i mean how to do it ? most visitors don't have an account, how to know which non logged-in users have already seen already the modal and which ones have not yet ?

Comment: I checked on few different iPhone (IOS11) and none of them had the `all cookies blocked = 'ON'`....

Comment: @Ben thanks a lot. maybe it's just my phone and my gf's :) reassuring. Still, what about all thèse who put it on, is there a way not to show them every visit the onboarding modal for new visitors ?

Comment: As @yeshashah said make a call to your backend saving that fact they saw it... And before showing it, make a new call to see if you have to show it or not. Of course you can't surely identify the user... You could use as much details as you have (like userAgent, screen resolution, IP address...) to make up an "almost" unique key

Comment: ok thanks for the second part of the comment. Indeed I can't use the table Users with a column has_already_seen_the_modal (true/false) as my "users" are web visitors without an account. and yes I guess i could use a mix of ip, user agent... might work but this complex code for precision I am not sure of, might not be worth if you say people by default have cookies unblocked.

Comment: @Mathieu  -> I did some reading and found this: iOS11 does introduce a cookie storing prevention mechanism called Intelligent Tracking Prevention but that affects only 3rd party cookies. On iOs11, the default setting for Managing Cookies is `Allow cookies from current websites` i.e. First party cookies. So your application should not have a problem. It should work fine. 
**Reference**: https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention/

Comment: @yeshashah could you post your answer so that I can attribute you the 50 
 bounty points ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some reading and found this:

> iOS11 does introduce a cookie storing prevention mechanism called
>   **Intelligent Tracking Prevention** but that affects only 3rd party
>   cookies. On iOs11, the default setting for Managing Cookies is **Allow
>   cookies from current websites** i.e. First party cookies.

So your application should not have a problem. 
It should work fine. Reference: https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention